# What does a Star in a Bottle do?

Tags: terraria

What does the Star in a Bottle do? I am new playing Terraria, so I want to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Wiki](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Star_in_a_Bottle):

> The Star in a Bottle is a lantern variant that provides players in its vicinity with an increased rate of mana regeneration.  The buff has a tile range of 50, similar to the Campfire and Heart Lantern.

You can hang the bottle from a ceiling and stand within 50 tiles to receive its buff.